# save stream to file in c# and winrt

Tags: c#, file, stream, save, windows-runtime

I have in c# and winrt:

```
var stream = await speech.GetSpeakStreamAsync(SpeechText.Text, language);
```

`stream` is a  `Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream`

So I am completly new to c# and winrt. How i save this stream containg a wav-file to a file?
Thanks in advance, Basilius

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IRandomAccessStream has a method called GetInputStreamAt http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream

```
IInputStream inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0);
```

This gets you an IInputStream.

The IInputStream interface defines just one method, ReadAsync, which lets you read bytes into an IBuffer object. Windows.Storage.Stream also includes a DataReader class that you create based on an IInputStream object and then read numerous .NET objects from the stream as well as arrays of bytes. http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2011/11/080203.html , http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208119

```
using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
{
    // for example, render pdf page
    var pdfPage = document.GetPage((uint)i);
    await pdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);

    // then, write page to file
    using (var reader = new DataReader(stream))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        var buffer = new byte[(int)stream.Size];
        reader.ReadBytes(buffer);
        await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buffer);
    }
}
```

now you have a buffer containing all the read bytes.

you can now save this buffer to a file http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html

```
var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyWav.wav", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it is late so I will try it tomorrow. the hint with getiputstremat and datareader seems very helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try it tomorrow because it is late. The hint with getinputstreamat and datareader seems very helpful. On winrt system.io.filestream is not available. Basilius

Comment: I Updated my answer. I thought you used winrt part of a desktop application, you were not particularily specific ;)

Comment: Hello Gerald, as I worte I am not so familar with c#, so I got some problemns with the code. I changed the language to vb.net and converted the code with an online translator. The line byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)size]; converted Dim Dateipuffer As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(gesprochenesWort.Size) - 1) {} made the code working. The resulting file was created but was not able to play by mediaplayer.  I suspeted that something with the buffer is noch coorrect and after a long searching i got a working code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add the code to the comment, so here is the code in vb.net:
Dim gesprochenesWort As Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream
        gesprochenesWort = Await Sprich.GetSpeakStreamAsync("Das ist ein Beispieltext", "de")

```
    Dim Eingabestream As Windows.Storage.Streams.IInputStream = gesprochenesWort.GetInputStreamAt(0)

    Dim Datenleser As New Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(Eingabestream)
    Await Datenleser.LoadAsync(CUInt(gesprochenesWort.Size))

    'Dim Dateipuffer As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(gesprochenesWort.Size) - 1) {}
    Dim Dateipuffer(gesprochenesWort.Size - 1) As Byte

    Datenleser.ReadBytes(Dateipuffer)

    Dim Dateiname As String = "MybestWav.wav"

    Dim Datei = Await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(Dateiname, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)

    Await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(Datei, Dateipuffer)
```

;Many thanks to you.

Best regards, Basilius