# UWP: byte[] to file

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have a `byte[]` and I want to store it into a file. This is my code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

StorageFolder folder = await GetStorageFolderFromFilePath(filePath);
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(filePath), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    IBuffer buffer = byteArray.AsBuffer();
    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
}
```

A file is created but the file is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why did you do not use `FileIO.WriteBytesAsync` method?

```
public static IAsyncAction WriteBytesAsync(IStorageFile file, System.Byte[] buffer);
```

You can do it in one line code:

```
await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(storageFile, byteArray);
```

Comment: Can you add the line of code where you create `storageFile`?

Comment: @Christian you can look this post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your solution here [save stream to file in c# and winrt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13336564/5969068)

basically, u need to read from your buffer.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should try this way:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path,bytes)
```

path - path to file,
bytes - file

Comment: It's code for usual Desktop C# version. You can't do it in Windows Phone / WinRT / UWP applications

Comment: System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes is available to UWP apps. Just make sure the path is in the app data folder for write access