# Access a StorageFile embedded as a resource in a Net Standard 2.0 class libary from UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

From UWP how do we access a file embedded as a resource in a .Net Standard 2 class library? The question [How to access content from a Net Standard 2.0 class libary from UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699649/how-to-access-content-from-a-net-standard-2-0-class-libary-from-uwp) returns a stream. How do we return a StorageFile?

The file is in a .Net Standard 2 project called Shared which is in the same solution as the UWP project. The file is in Shared/Reports and is set to copy to output as EmbeddedResource.

I've tried

```
Uri resourcePath = new Uri("ms-appx:///Shared/Reports/MyReport");
StorageFile myFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(resourcePath);
```

and

```
Uri resourcePath = new Uri("Shared/Reports/MyReport");
StorageFile myFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(resourcePath);
```

Both return `FileNotFoundException`.

Is `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` the appropriate method? If so, how do I correctly format the URI?

Comment: What did you want to do by accessing the StorageFile? In general, you could get the same target by using file stream.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier Xie - MSFT  I know how to retrieve the target as a stream. but I need to return a StorageFile object.

Comment: You could create a StorageFile in local folder and write to it. Please check the similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336341/save-stream-to-file-in-c-sharp-and-winrt

Comment: Thanks you once again @@Xavier Xie - MSFT. I don't understand the example you referenced and I note the OP couldn't get it to work either. How is InMemoryRandomAccessStream() used to read from a file embedded as a resource in a .Net Standard 2 class library? The InMemoryRandomAccessStream() docs are from Windows 8.1.

Comment: You said you want to get a StorageFile, but with the above method that you mention in your original post, you could only get the stream. Then, I told you to try to save stream to a StorageFile.

Comment: Yes but the example given A: doesn't work and B: uses methods specific to pdfiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes but the example given A: doesn't work and B: uses methods specific to pdfiles.

It's OK. The link that I mentioned in the above comment is just a similar question. My purpose was to tell you to save stream into a StorageFile. But it seemed that you're not familiar with it.

I've made a code sample for your reference.

```
public class Class1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the method in my .Net Standard library
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Stream GetImage()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Class1).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ClassLibrary1.Assets.dog.jpg");
        return stream;
    }
}
```

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is used to create a StorageFile and save the stream into it, then return this StorageFile
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<StorageFile> GetFile()
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("Temp.jpg",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var Srcstream = ClassLibrary1.Class1.GetImage())
        {
            using (var targetStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var reader = new DataReader(Srcstream.AsInputStream()))
                {
                    var outpustream = targetStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
                    await reader.LoadAsync((uint)Srcstream.Length);
                    while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength >0)
                    {
                        uint datatoend = reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 128 ? 128 : reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
                        IBuffer buffer = reader.ReadBuffer(datatoend);
                        await outpustream.WriteAsync(buffer);
                    }
                    await outpustream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        return storageFile;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Xavier Xie - MSFT. That's what I call an answer. It's complete in itself. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide the using directives you ? Also what .NET Framework? Can this be used on Xamarn.Forms for UWP targeting .NET Standard 2.0?